# How to find if array value changed or not in PHP

Tags: php

We have a array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [HASTANEADI] => MALATYA DEVLET HASTANESİ
            [SEHIR] => Malatya
            [DONEM] => NİSAN 2011
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [HASTANEADI] => MALATYA DEVLET HASTANESİ
            [SEHIR] => Malatya
            [DONEM] => MART 2011

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [HASTANEADI] => MALATYA DEVLET HASTANESİ
            [SEHIR] => Malatya
            [DONEM] => OCAK 2011

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [HASTANEADI] => DENİZLİ DEVLET HASTANESİ
            [SEHIR] => Denizli
            [DONEM] => NİSAN 2011

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [HASTANEADI] => DENİZLİ DEVLET HASTANESİ
            [SEHIR] => Denizli
            [DONEM] => MART 2011

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [HASTANEADI] => DENİZLİ DEVLET HASTANESİ
            [SEHIR] => Denizli
            [DONEM] => OCAK 2011

        )
```

I want to get DONEM  for HASTANE one time.I want to write DONEM values not every HASTANE.Because DONEM  for same every HASTANE

So  I tried this code:

```
$categories="";
foreach ($hastane as $h) {

     $categories.="'$h['DONEM']',";


    }

 echo $categories;



'NİSAN 2011','MART 2011','OCAK 2011','NİSAN 2011','MART 2011','OCAK 2011',
```

But I want to output like this:

```
 'NİSAN 2011','MART 2011','OCAK 2011',
```

I dont want to DONEM values to dublicate.
So How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: as @zerkms says, you can try array_unique -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @MarcoMura as you say as I've said - indeed

Comment: dang, didnt even think of array_unique. Totally overthought it :/

Answer (score 1):

One option would be this:

```
$unique = array();
foreach ($hastane as $h) {
  $unique[$h['DONEM']] = 1;
}

$categories="";
foreach(array_keys($unique) as $donem){
  $categories.= "'{$donem}',";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the comments above, one way would be to use `array_unique()`. Gather all the values in your desired array, then apply the function. To present them, just use `implode()`:

```
$DONEM = array();
foreach($array as $values) {
    $DONEM[] = "'" . $values['DONEM'] . "'";
}

$DONEM = array_unique($DONEM);
echo implode(', ', $DONEM);
```

If you're already using PHP 5.5 or greater, you can also use `array_column`.

```
$DONEM = array_unique(array_column($array, 'DONEM'));
echo implode(', ', $DONEM);
```